# Why did Stack Overflow not maintain its own DNS services?

Tags: discussion, architecture

I am reading up on DNS and came across [an article](https://blog.serverfault.com/2017/01/09/surviving-the-next-dns-attack/#:%7E:text=Our%20initial%20rollout%20of%20DNS%20was%20using%20Amazon,are%20all%20priced%20identically%20for%20basic%20DNS%20services%29) in which it's mentioned that Stack Overflow chose to go with 3rd party services because of maintenance complexity (paraphrasing). I find it hard to believe that engineers at Stack Overflow could not automate something like that. Why did Stack Overflow go with a 3rd party provider? Was it because it was cheaper long term? It's unlikely that 3rd party services are cheaper long term because they are usually more expensive.

Comment: Questions about company decisions should probably be asked on https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can't think of the last time I've seen a website using their own DNS servers (outside of companies that also provide DNS). DNS service providers generally aren't that expensive, and their ability to have worldwide distribution, SLAs, robust design and failure protection, etc, makes them rather worthwhile.

Comment: It's probably risk vs reward... What is there to gain? What is there to lose? I don't see the benefit, ye there's a lot of downsides...

Comment: Most of the time, the answer is: don't [reinvent the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel), even for [syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/241919)

Comment: "I find it hard to believe that engineers at Stack Overflow could not automate something like that." How many companies can you name that *did* automate it?

Answer (score 16):

Disclaimer: I am a current user of Cloudflare. While I use Cloudflare as an example, that is primarily because I am most familiar with them, not because I'm a spammer.

---

There isn't much benefit to. There's many companies that provides DNS services (Cloudflare, Google, Microsoft, etc.)*. Some ISPs also run a DNS server for their users to improve caching.

But... these companies have created (typically) very robust DNS services. They also, in many cases, have a global network of data centers for faster speeds. On top of that,  they also often offer SLAs (as vandench mentioned). Not always, but many providers (such as Cloudflare) also provide services such as DDOS attack prevention, and that is often extremely difficult to DIY for a number of reasons (that are beyond the scope of this answer).

As one example, if you compare a small cloud VM (such as one from AWS or Azure) to Cloudflare, you'll find the VM isn't actually that capable. Let's say you purchase a VPS for, say, $6/month. Chances are you'll get a gigabit network connection, one or two CPUs, and maybe a gigabyte of RAM. If you install a DNS server on it, requests to it from nearby places may work decently. If you make a DNS query from the other side of the globe, the latency will likely be rather poor, as your VPS is only in one datacenter. Also, if someone DDOS's you, you can't do much about it with your entire... one gigabit speed limit.

In contrast, the Cloudflare free plan lets you create DNS entries and uses a *global* network to make it significantly faster around the globe. In contrast to our hypothetical one gigabit of capacity, the Cloudflare network as 209 *terabits* of capacity. Cloudflare also includes *unmetered* and *unlimited* DDOS protection on *all* plans, for no cost. Even the free plan. You simply won't get DDOS protection of that level with a DIYed option for $10/month.

Note that the $10/month VPS has *vastly* less capacity to handle attacks, and it doesn't even factor in that there won't be an SLA. Of course, it also doesn't include a bandwidth cap *anywhere close* to Cloudflare.

Given that there are a number of existing providers with an already-build global network, there... isn't much value in re-doing what already exists for DNS. That's not to say it is *impossible*, but... there would need to be some good reason that none of the existing providers would work.

Some places, and even some home users, might run their own *local*/*internal* DNS server for local-only servers, such as if I want to have `nas.example.com` go to the NAS on my local network. But that's *very* different than running a *public* DNS server for anyone to use.

Comment: its cheaper to run it in house almost always. I did the math.

Comment: @Vishal - It might be cheaper but is it more reliable. Can you achieve six 9’s in-house for the same price as offloading that stress to somebody else?

Comment: @Vishal please share that math. I'd be very surprised if that's true if you account for the personnel required to maintain a high-availability DNS solution.

Comment: @ErikA Sure, so there are 2,628,000 seconds in a month. A small 1vCPU can process 5000-1000 DNS queries per second easy. That gives you a total of 13B-26B request per month. Route 53 charges .40/M requests, a total of ~5-10k per month + data transfer. 1vCPU EC2 cost ~$10 + data transfer. On top of that you dont have to worry about someone DOSing your service and you being billed for the garbage requests.

Comment: @SecurityHound You would have the same reliability as your other VMs. What good is a 99999999999 DNS VM when others arent the same?

Comment: @Vishal: You know, if you see daylight between the prices changed by third-party DNS companies and the actual costs, then you might have a business opportunity for yourself.

Comment: Not implying it would be sufficient for SO, but as an example, look up the Cloudflare free plan. It is entirely free, yet it includes unlimited DDOS protection through the global Cloudflare network. You’re not going to get that level of DDOS protection with a $10 VPS. Latency from different places will also be worse compared to a company with a global network of data centers. Disclaimer: I do use Cloudflare, but I am not affiliated with them.

Comment: @Vishal did you actually read the article you linked to? How your "use one random VM in AWS" solution will *guarantee* sub-100ms response across the globe? The monitoring solution alone described in the article is probably hundreds of hours... and that to just measure performance once without need to immediately respond... I'm with Erik A - showing math for actual approach (rather than "I can handle 1000 RPS on my phone" math you've added to the comment)   would be nice.